# Index of the last substring

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to write program that returns the index of the substring.

But if I have two strings like these:

```
(go-substring)

# ex. mango go man - go
```

`"mango go man"` is the main string in which we are finding `"go"`, the substring.

I want the program to return 7 and not 4. I think the problem is is that it doesn't go through the entire string, but I don't understand why.

```
int findsub(const char *str1,const char *str2)
{
    int l1=0,l2=0;

    while(*(str1+l1)!='\0')
    {
        l1++;
    }

    while(*(str2+l2)!='\0')
    {
        l2++;
    }

    int i,j;

    for(i=0,j=0;*(str1+i)!='\0'&&*(str2+j)!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(*(str1+i)==*(str2+j))
        j++;
    }

    if(j==l2)
    {
        return i-j+1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered _going backwards_ through the string?

Comment: use strstr, kepp going till it says there are no more martches

Comment: `returns the index of the substring` & `I want the program to return 7 and not 4`... The correct index values would be 6 and 3... The values 7 and 4 are not the indices you are looking for... (OT: why do two other responses refer to "going" somewhere??? :-)

Comment: What's the purpose of `l1`?? Why is this code present?

Comment: this code looks for the first occurrence, it can be replaced by `strstr(str1,str2)`. As i said before, loop until strstr says it didnt find anything, then use the previous match

Comment: Hint: Instead of "upshifting" the index (if found) so that `0` becomes `1`, simply return `-1` (an impossible index based on `str1` being the start of the array) if the target string is not found.

Comment: @pm100 It is very likely this is a homework. Using `strstr()` would very likely defeat the learning objectives.

Comment: @pi p, Please explain the role of `"(go-substring)"`.  How is that used here?  What is your definition of `sub-string?  Space seperated words?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I just wanted to state that "mango go man" is the main string in which we are finding "go", the substring.

Comment: @pip With `str1 = "mango go man"`, and `str2 = "go"`, `"go"` starts at `&str1[6]`.  Why do you want 7 and not 6?

Answer (score 0):

You don't return counter j to 0 so after it saw first go in "mango" the condition of if it will not work any more

That code will solve your problem but you have another problem which is the algorithm will work if it found the characters of the second string even if it's separated

Try to put space between 'g' and 'o' and it will work, To find the whole word you will need to use nested loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findsub(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    int l1 = 0, l2 = 0;

    while (*(str1 + l1) != '\0')
    {
        l1++;
    }

    while (*(str2 + l2) != '\0')
    {
        l2++;
    }

    int i, j, x;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; *(str1 + i) != '\0' && *(str2 + j) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (*(str1 + i) == *(str2 + j))
        {
            j++;
            x = i;
        }

        if (j == l2 - 1)
        {
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    return x + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int num = findsub("mango go man", "go");
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```